# How do you express symbollically that an equation doesn't have solution over the reals?

Tags: context-free-grammar

This is a really quick doubt, i'm just curious about how it will be. Imagine an equation like $\cos(x)=\sqrt{-1}$, it obviously doesn't have solutions over the reals, how do I express it symbollically? (e.g using mathematical language, as $\exists$ or $\not\exists$, etc.) I've thought of something like $\not\exists x\in\mathbb{R}:\cos(x)=\sqrt{-1}$?

Comment: $\{x\in\Bbb R~:~\cos(x)=\sqrt{-1}\}=\emptyset$ is another option.  That is to say, the set of solutions to the equation is empty.

Comment: oh thanks! my attempt was correct too?

Comment: Yes, what you wrote was correct, but I think writing it in words is best.

Comment: i want to learn more about mathematical language and stuff like this, does this topic have a name to investigate on it more?

Comment: First-order logic, or predicate logic. Also, I think the best notation here will be $\forall x \in \mathbb R: \cos(x) \neq \sqrt{-1}$ (although it's closer to "no real is a solution" than to "there are no real solutions").